# Configuring a replica set of Spring Boot back-end that uses a Postgresql db

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, openshift, load-balancing, replicaset

i am quite new to spring-boot. I have a typical application that consists of a front-end, back-end and postgresql database (see below).

I deployed this app to a local openshift with one pod for each. The app worked fine but when i try though to replicate the spring-boot-backend-pods i noticed that only one of the replicas can access the database. I thought at first that this is happening due to RWO Access Mode of the postgresql volume so i changed it to shared acess(RWX) but i still having the problem.

error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sensor type ST0001 already exists
    at com.foo.boo.SupplyChainController.addSensorType(SupplyChainController.kt:138) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.foo.boo.SupplyChainController.initializeSupplyChain(SupplyChainController.kt:203) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.foo.boo.service.SupplyChainService.instatiateSupplyChain(SupplyChainService.java:41) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.foo.boo.websocket.SupplyChainSocketController.instatiateSupplyChain(SupplyChainSocketController.java:32) ~[classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.messaging.support.ExecutorSubscribableChannel$SendTask.run(ExecutorSubscribableChannel.java:138) [spring-messaging-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]`

Does any body know whats really happening here? I can provide more info if needed.

[image: app]

Comment: Could you add the error that you see in the pods that can't access? Are they all accessing the Postgres via a Service?

Comment: @RyanDawson yes they are accessing the Postgres via a kubernetes service named `postgres`